# Data not saved with attr_encryptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encryption, rails-postgresql

I would like to encrypt data in my project so I use https://github.com/danpal/attr_encryptor
I use this gem like this for my User model for example :

```
attr_accessible :name, :mail
attr_accessor :name
attr_encryptor :name, :charset => 'UTF-8', :key => 'mysecretkey'
```

My problem is that name isn't saved, I don't have any errors...
In my database, I have USER(mail, encrypted_name, encrypted_name_salt, encrypted_name_iv)

Do you know the reason ? Is there anybody here with a functionnal example of encryption ? 
For information, I use PostgreSQL.

Thanks.

Comment: I have an error now "column "name" of relation "user" does not exist".With better_errors, when I wrote @user.encrypted_name I have a value, what could be wrong ??